# Check if input has text/value with CSS

Tags: html, css, input

I've looked around a bit but can only find JS solutions to this.

Is there a way with CSS to detect if an input has any text entered?

What I'm doing is basically this (cut out the irrelevant code for this question):

```
 .search-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 0 !important;
}
.search-form input[type="text"]:focus {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Essentially, clicking on the label expands the input to 100% of the page width. This works fine, but when you enter text and click off the input, it shrinks back to width:0 - therefore hiding the inputted text. Is there a way with CSS to prevent this behaviour and keep it at `width:100%` like when the input is `:focus` when there's text inputted?

Comment: Is there any reason to why you cant use JS?

Comment: Provide us a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can help you a bit more

Comment: Pretty sure you need JS for this, CSS use logic or have conditionals so without that I don't see any way of doing this.

Comment: @KM123, no not really, I was just trying to work out the most lightweight option and thought there might be some kind of selector or workaround for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would seriously consider using a light framework like jQuery. Would you like me to provide you the code to acheive what you want?

Comment: This cannot be done with JavaScript. The focus IS simply saying make me big when I get focus, and make me small when I lose focus. And that is exactly what the code is doing :)

Answer (score 9):

Try adding the "required" property to the text field in the HTML, and then add this to the CSS:

```
.search-form input[type="text"]:valid {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

I would probably try to avoid all those !importants though.

Comment: I was thinking this could work, and built [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/9nvTK/) to try it after you posted.

Comment: This is just beautiful!

Comment: And what if you would like submit form and element must be optional?? This will not working... (jQuery validate do not submit form...)

Comment: must be a better way than valid

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work for your specific use case, but you could achieve the effect with a fake input, using [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/DbL9X/4/)**

```
 .fakeInput {
     border: 1px solid red;
     display:inline;
     padding:2px; /* optional */
 }
 .fakeInput:focus {
     display:block;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     width:100%;
     height:1em;
 }

<div class="search-form">
    <div class="fakeInput" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```